# How to compare each element in two arrays with time complexity less than O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Suppose we have two arrays A[n] and b[n], the goal is to compare every element in A to elements in B. Then return a list result[n] that records the number of each element in A that is larger than the elements in B.

For example,

> A = [38, 24, 43, 3], B = [9, 82, 10, 11]

Since 38 is larger than 9, 10 and 11, so result[0] is 3. 
Then result is [3, 3, 3, 0].

It will be the best if you can provide some pseudocode.

Thank you.

Comment: It will be great if you provide some of your ideas.

Comment: If they were both  sorted it would be easy to step through the lists in O(n) and find the index in B at which the elements become bigger than each element in A.

Comment: Can you please provide some link from where you got this problem ? like leetcode, geeksforgeeks, hackerrank etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform the above algorithm in O(nlogn) complexity where n is the length of array A and array B as given in the question.

## Algorithm

```
1. Sort both the arrays A and B, this will take O(nlogn) time complexity.
2. Take two pointers i and j, initialize both of them to 0. we will use i for array A and j for B.
3. Create a result array res of size n.
4. Start a while loop 
   while(i<n && j<n) {
     if(A[i] > B[j]) {
       j++;
     } else {
       res[i] = j+1;
       i++;
     }
   }
5. while(i<n) {
     res[i] = n;
   }
   This step is for the case where all elements in A are bigger than all elements in B.
```

At the end you will have `res` array ready with the answer.

Overall time complexity - `O(nlogn)`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is just brilliant!! Thank you so much. By the way, the worst running time for the loop at step 4 should be O(n), right?

Comment: @Zack this gives the wrong value, and if any values in A are bigger than all of the values in B then you get incomplete results. Try my answer.

Comment: @Richardissimo thanks a lot for pointing out the bug in my program, I have fixed it . I forgot to cover the case, when providing the answer, my main aim what to cover main logic for the algorithm.

Comment: Even after the edit, it's still not correct, which makes it frustrating that it's marked as the accepted answer and has been upvoted when mine is correct and hasn't.

Comment: @Richardissimo what is the case that I am missing, we can improve the answer.

Comment: I've already given a working answer to this question, why is there a need to help improve a different answer? Take a look at my answer, see if you agree it's helpful, and if so, upvote it. Maybe you'll spot your mistake.

Comment: @zenwraight your res list will not be updated when i = n-1 and j = n-1. so u need to keep your line algo's 6 and 7 in an "else if" and the only "if" would contain the condition (i==n-1 and j==n-1 and A[i]>B[j]), then do j+=1 and do append j to the list. Also your else part will not work right, it'll make j one bigger than it should be. so keep res[i] = j, not res[i] = j+1.

Answer (score -1):

Both lists need to be sorted ascending for this to work.

Sorting costs [O(log n)](http://bigocheatsheet.com). And big-O arithmetic means doing it twice is still `O(n log n)`. I'm going to assume they are already sorted. The remaining work below doesn't affect the big-O cost.

Have an index to the `B` array called `indexB`, value zero (my pseudocode will use zero-based indexing). And `indexA` for `A` also starting at zero.

```
indexA=0
For each indexB from 0 to B.Length-1
    While indexA < A.Length and the value at `A[indexA]` is less than or equal to the value at `B[indexB]`
        Set the `result[indexA]` to be `indexB`
        Increment `indexA`
    Endwhile
Endfor
```

After that, all of the remaining items in the `result` from `indexA` onward are bigger than all the items in `B`, so set the rest of them to `B.Length`.

---

**Edited 2 years after posting my original answer, to add:** actual C# code to reflect the above pseudocode. I believe the code below to be `O(n)`, which is negligible (in big-O terms) compared to the cost of the sorting of the arrays in the first place, so the overall cost remains `O(n log n)`.

```cs
            // Note: I am simulating pre-sorted arrays, which costs "O(n log n)"...
            // The reason for adding this sample code is to help clarify the cost of the
            // remaining work (after the sorts) by showing real code, to avoid any
            // ambiguity from the pseudocode, even though that's what the OP asked for
            var A = new[] { 3, 24, 38, 43 };
            var B = new[] { 9, 10, 11, 82 };
            var result = new int[4];

            int indexA = 0;
            for (int indexB = 0; indexB < B.Length; indexB++)
            {
                while (indexA < A.Length && A[indexA] <= B[indexB])
                {
                    result[indexA] = indexB;
                    indexA++;
                }
            }

            while (indexA < A.Length)
            {
                result[indexA] = B.Length;
                indexA++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Comment: Here I can see a nested while inside a fo each. The complexity will be O(n^2)

Comment: @jithil It isn't iterating over all of the items inside each loop. You need to actually look at the logic. Try following what happens to `indexA`.

Comment: But, in Big O , O(n*(n/2)) => O(n^2) since constants will be excluded.

Comment: @jithil where are you getting the `n/2` and why are you multiplying it by `n`? The "for" loop is `n`, and the "while" loop within it is **independent** of the for loop which contains it, and is also `n`. So it will perform the work `n+n` times, which is `O(2*n)`, which is equivalent to `O(n)`.

Comment: @jithil I'm still keen to understand your reasoning, if you will share it?

Comment: Please consider the worst case. I calculated the n^2 by seeing the worst cases. I can't give further answers since this question is already down voted.

the nested for loop will create n^2 even you are not intending to execute n times inside a loop. I may be wrong. so, please apologise.

or I can respond, if you can come with detailed example.

Comment: @jithil Please look at the code and try running it. Add you own breakpoints or messages to it. The worst case is `n+n`. In fact that's *always* the number of times it will do it. With 4 items, it does 8 pieces of work, not 16. If there were 1000 items in each of A and B, it would do 2000 pieces of work, not one million.