# Finding pairs of vectors where no element of the first is less than that element in the second

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This is a generalization of [How to compare each element in two arrays with time complexity less than O(n^2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135373). Say we have two matrices A and B of size nxk and mxk, addressable as `A[row][col]` and `B[row][col]`. Let a pair `(i, j)` be acceptable if for every `r`, `A[i][r] >= B[j][r]`. Is there any way of identifying every acceptable pair quicker than the naive O(nmk)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
        bool accept = true;
        for (int r = 0; r < k && accept; ++r) {
            accept &= (A[i][r] >= B[j][r]);
        }
        if (accept) { std::cout << i << ", " << j << "\n"; }
    }
}
```

?

If k=1, then I can use the solution implied by the linked question to do the task in n log n time. However, when k>1, it gets more difficult due to matrices like this:

```
A[0] = {1, 1}
A[1] = {3, 1}
A[2] = {3, 5}
A[3] = {5, 3}
A[4] = {5, 5}

B[0] = {2, 4}
B[1] = {4, 2}
```

The acceptable pairs are (2, 0), (4, 0), (3, 1), and (4, 1). Sorting by the first element gives the order above, where what's acceptable to B=1 is contiguous (A=3 and A=4), but what's acceptable to B=0 is not. Sorting by the second element similarly makes what's acceptable to B=0 contiguous and what's acceptable to B=1 not. Doing one pass of sorting and reading off contiguous ranges like the k=1 solution doesn't seem to work.

The particular setting I have in mind for the problem has n and m on the order of millions, and k on the order of a thousand, so nmk time is not very practical.

Comment: Is the output from your algorithm supposed to be a list of acceptable pairs, or just the count of acceptable pairs? Because if the output is a list of pairs, then the size of the output itself is O(nm). That's not practical when `n` and `m` are in the millions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the output can be `nm`, so the algorithm cannot have better performance than O(nm). Improving the average case is certainly possible but depends a lot on your data and distribution. Here are some generic tips:

If you can afford m * k memory, you can keep a sorted list of B indexes ordered by the first column value. The same for second column, and so on. With this structure + binary search, you can answer the question of given a fixed column c and fixed number x, how many B[j][c] <= x there are in O(log m).

Then for every value x in A[i], you can check how many B[j][c] <= x there are. Sort them by this quantity. The first value (let's call it L1) will be the lowest number, so you will compare against B from the sorted list by that column. By using binary search, you can skip the beginning and only compare against L1 arrays of B.

Instead of comparing column by column in any order, you can compare in the order we kept from the B[j][c] <= x calculations. That will mean that the second value we use from A, will have the lowest chance against the rest of the columns of being lower than the ones in B. This will help with minimizing comparisons for pairs that don't satisfy the conditions.

Comment: That's a good point, that it will in any case be O(nm); so I must be implicitly assuming that there are very few hits. Using this assumption will cause the worst case runtime to go beyond O(nmk), but that's okay as long as I expect my data to give a better runtime than what the naive one would do.

Comment: Yeah many algorithms try to do better at the average case at the cost of worse worst case, like quicksort. When you have examples to test against, timing it against standard one is a good strategy.