# How can I reduce big O (n ^ 2) complexity of two for loops

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

I had 2 arrays (txs and interval) and I want the interval to includes txs which had a date between from and to (include).

```
const txs = [
   { price: 1, date: 1 },
   { price: 3, date: 2 },
   { price: 1.7, date: 4 }
];
```

```
const interval = [
   { from: 1, to: 2, txs: [] },
   { from: 2, to: 3, txs: [] },
   { from: 3, to: 4, txs: [] }
];
```

expected result

```
[
   { from: 1, to: 2, txs: [{ price: 1 }, { price: 3 }] },
   { from: 2, to: 3, txs: [{ price: 3 }] },
   { from: 3, to: 4, txs: [{ price: 1.7 }] }
]
```

And this is my solution in O(n^2)

```
for (let i of interval) {
  for (let j of txs) {
     if (j.date >= i.from && j.date <= i.to) {
        i.txs.push({ price: j.price });
     }
  }
}
```

this is only an example. the real one txs and interval could have more than 10,000 elements.
is there any solution that can be done in O(n) or O(n log n) ?

Comment: Is this not already O(n), both in the number of elements of `interval` and the number of elements in `txs`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135665/1046690

Comment: @Frederik this is only an example. the real one txs and interval could have more than 10,000 elements.

Comment: You can optimize by sorting the `txs` array and do a binary search in the nested loop instead of iteration. Then you get `n + log(n)` which is slightly better than `n^2`.

Comment: If the interval array has differents interval values, you can delete all elements pusheds of txs array. So, number of iterations "for (let j of txs)"  is lower than start

Comment: If your interval is consistent in size and bounded, then you can treat your interval as a series of buckets, and simply walk the `txs` array, calculating the bucket to which it belongs.  This will be on order of O(n), but your space requirement will likely increase if the `txs` array is somewhat sparse or heavy on a few buckets, as there will be a lot of empty buckets.  Plus you will need to know the bounds of the `txs` dates in order to set up the array of interval buckets...  Then, another O(n) sweep is required to remove empty buckets...

Comment: @Trentium: `consistent in size and bounded` non-overlapping, rather?

Comment: @greybeard the intervals could be overlapping, and as long as the overlap was consistent in size, then in theory one could determine if the `txs` entry belonged to two buckets rather than one...

Comment: @Kobayashi what say ye concerning the regularity of the intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me call the length of `txs` *n* and that of `intervals` *m*. Following [cucaracho's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456259/how-can-i-reduce-big-o-n-2-complexity-of-two-for-loops#comment122765566_69456259), you have one O(*n* log(*n*)) precomputation. Finding the *first* "txs" to include (if any) takes O(log *n*) for each interval. Adding one txs should take O(1) for a total of O(*n* log(*n*) + *m* log(*n*) + *mn*) = O((*n* + *m*) log(*n*) + *mn*).
To get that annoying term *mn* ("size of output") out of the picture, find the first txs *not* to include and for each interval represent the txss to include by specifying this one in addition to the first.

For non-overlapping intervals, just ordering both arrays and walking both *may* be faster, one influence being relative array size.